# svg elements within an iframe that have a clip-path attribute do not render properly in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, iframe, svg, microsoft-edge, clip

I have a simple iframe without a src attribute to allow for style sandboxing from its containing document.  The clip-path attributes on svg elements seem to work great in Chrome, but does not work correctly in Edge.

**Code**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="expected"></div>
      <hr>
      <iframe id="myiframe" style="border: 0px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
      var iframeDoc = document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.document;
      var svgStr = '<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><clipPath id="myClip"><circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20"/><circle cx="70" cy="70" r="20"/></clipPath></defs><rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/></svg>';

      document.getElementById("expected").innerHTML = svgStr;
      iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = svgStr;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The top portion of the output is the svg directly embedded into the page -- works great.  The bottom portion is the svg embedded into an iframe on the page -- doesn't work.

An example fiddle that exhibits the issue is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m0om8tzv/).

Am I missing something to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

This same issue also happens for `mask="url(#mask)"`. It happens because Edge tries to resolve the `#mask` or `#myClip` reference in the parent frame. In order to force it to resolve it inside of the iframe, add the location of the iframe in front of the hash:

```
var rect = '<rect ... clip-path="url(' + document.location + '#mask)" />';
```

Comment: I tried this and not work, could you provide a code sample about this fix?